# Importing Data from specific excel sheets from multiple workbooks in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I need to pull the data from specific sheets in multiple excel workbooks into a master copy. I've managed to make one which pulls from every sheet in the workbooks but cant figure out how to make it pull the data from a specified sheet. My code is below:

```
    Sub getDataFromWbs()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'This is where you put YOUR folder name
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Matthew.Stokes.Hughe\Desktop\test 2\Temp\")

    'Next available Row on Master Workbook
    y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Loop through each file in that folder
    For Each wbFile In fldr.Files

        'Make sure looping only through files ending in .xlsx (Excel files)
        If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then

          'Open current book
          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)

          'Loop through each sheet (ws)
          For Each ws In wb.Sheets

          'Last row in that sheet (ws)
              wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

              'Loop through each record (row 2 through last row)
              For x = 2 To wsLR
                'Put column 1,2,3 and 4 of current sheet (ws) into row y of master sheet, then increase row y to next row
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1) 'col 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2) 'col 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 3) = ws.Cells(x, 3) 'col 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = ws.Cells(x, 4) 'col 1
                y = y + 1
              Next x

            Next ws

          'Close current book
          wb.Close
        End If

    Next wbFile

    End Sub
```

The Name of the Specified sheets to draw the information from is Sheet 1.
Any help would be great!

Comment: What's happening? Your code on the surface seems okay. Are you getting any data to your Sheet1 workbook?

Comment: I'm getting data from every sheet in the source workbooks, whereas i only want to get it from one of the sheets (Data). I'm not sure how to specify to only pull from that one sheet.

Comment: I posted an answer. You just need to run the code when the name matches. Please be sure to accept the answer. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I see you changed the name of the sheet you need from "DATA" to "Sheet 1". That shouldn't matter in the answer, just adjust my code for the line that says `if WS.Name = "Sheet 1" Then `. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help, one last thing, is there anyway to shorten the 
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1) 'col 1 lines as i just realised i need to pull 69 different data points

Comment: you could use a loop, but it will only save you 1 line of code. I'll include in the answer. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to an if-statement to check the name:

```
Sub getDataFromWbs()

  Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  'This is where you put YOUR folder name
  Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Matthew.Stokes.Hughe\Desktop\test 2\Temp\")

  'Next available Row on Master Workbook
  y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  'Loop through each file in that folder
  For Each wbFile In fldr.Files

      'Make sure looping only through files ending in .xlsx (Excel files)
      If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then

        'Open current book
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)

        'Loop through each sheet (ws)
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
  
          'check WS name
          If UCase(ws.Name) = "DATA" Then
  
        'Last row in that sheet (ws)
            wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'Loop through each record (row 2 through last row)
            For x = 2 To wsLR
            
              Dim c As Long
              For c = 1 To 4
              'Put column 1,2,3 and 4 of current sheet (ws) into row y of master sheet, then increase row y to next row
                  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, c) = ws.Cells(x, c) 'col 1
              Next c
              
              y = y + 1
            Next x
          
          End If
          Next ws

        'Close current book
        wb.Close
      End If

  Next wbFile

  End Sub
```