# Is there a way to export the same specific cells from multiple excel workbooks, into one excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an Excel sheet refund request form. I managed to make a button that prints 2 copies and saves it as a filled form. But I'd like to be able to upload a summary of the form (4 specific cells - date, name, item name, item ID code) to Google spreadsheets. To make it easier, I'd like to make a master workbook, from where I'd copy and paste a summary of all forms filled this day.

I've tried looking into excel-google sheets integration through API, but I'm not a programmer and the topic overwhelmed me.

I've also found this topic: [Importing Data from specific excel sheets from multiple workbooks in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076248/importing-data-from-specific-excel-sheets-from-multiple-workbooks-in-a-folder)

But code there copies entire columns, while I need only 4 specific cells.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    response = MsgBox("Jesteś pewien?", vbYesNo)

    If response = vbNo Then
        MsgBox ("Macro Ending")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim path As String
    Dim filename1 As String

    path = "D:\filled forms\"

    filename1 = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & Range("C9") & " " & Range("G6")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1 & ".xlsm",
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=2, Collate:=False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        .Range("E29").Copy
        With Workbooks("mastersheet.xlsx").Worksheets("Arkusz1")
            Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't copy over the cell's content, and I end up with empty workbook.

Edit: I've managed to find a solution, this is how it looks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

response = MsgBox("Jesteś pewien?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbNo Then
    MsgBox ("Akcja anulowana.")
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String

path = "D:\"

filename1 = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & Range("C9") & " " & Range("G6")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=2, Collate:=False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C34:F34").Copy
Workbooks("analiza.xlsx").Worksheets("arkusz1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to put a `.` in front of your last use of `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` and in front of the `Rows` also. Because you're using a `With` statement, you want the `Cells` to be pasted on the `Arkusz1` worksheet. (This is the same as the `.Range` statement above, associating with `sheet1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy just the cells you like this:

```
Dim fromData As Range
Set fromData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E29:E31")

Dim toData As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
With Workbooks("mastersheet.xlsx").Worksheets("Arkusz1")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set toData = .Range(.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1), .Cells(lastRow + 3), 1))
End With
toData.Value = fromData.Value
```

Comment: Unfortunately, a new problem arrived. The code only pastes "#######" (on mouseover shows the date that was copied) in cells A1:A4, instead of copying content from cells E29:H29 to cells A1:D1. May I ask for your help with that?

Comment: That generally means that the column width is too narrow to display the full value. Try making the column wider.